# How to cast data to different types in Javascript, just like in Java?

Tags: javascript, casting

I wanted to make this Encoding/Decoding Javascript function, which I used to make in Java, but I haven't figured out how to cast bytes to a different types. Simply, I want to make this, but in Javascript :

```
(Java)
String input = "something", mssg;
int key = 12;
for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
   mssg = mssg + (char) (input[i] ^ key);
}
return mssg;
```

See the ***(char)*** there? I have no idea how to do that in Javascript.
To encode a character, or in Javascript's case, a Symbol, using the XOR operation with number 'key' to XOR the bytes of the symbol and then make a String out of it, which you can, by XORing the String by the same key, decode.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no `char` type in JavaScript. But perhaps you want to use the [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) function of JavaScript strings to get the integral value of a character of the string

Comment: It's `input[i]`.

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine No, it's a String you can't index that. That's why there's a charAt method.

Comment: @Kvicala0 You can index strings in JavaScript. Mind you, JavaScript and Java are different languages.

Answer (score 0):

To get the integer code for a character in a string, use [`charCodeAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

To get a string from one or multiple character codes, use [`fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode).